# print a list in a square pattern [python]

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list, for example:

```
x = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9],
      [10, 11, 12]]
```

in a certain pattern like below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

but I couldn't figure it out.

In Java a simple nested `for` loop will do the job but not in Python. This is what I tried:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        print(x[i][j])
```

But this just prints each number in a new line.

Comment: "print" function has an optional parameter to specify if a newline should be printed at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: no, end='' " will keep everything in one line

Comment: I want to print first row and new line then second row and new line and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` takes an optional parameter `end`:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        print(x[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: this prints everything in a newline

Comment: My output for this code is exactly how you have specified in the question. Please recheck the code you have copy/pasted.

Answer (score 1):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has some useful extra arguments. So:

You can either print each cell with an empty `end` and add a new line after each row:

```py
for row in x:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end=" ")
    print()
```

Or, print each line with an empty `sep`:

```py
for row in x:
    print(*row, sep=" ")
```

Or finally use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to combine all rows:

```py
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(cell) for cell in row) for row in x))
```